# VLC 3.0 (flatpak) data location

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, vlc, flatpak

I want to install tunein.lua plugin on VLC 3.0 (**flatpak**). System: Linux Mint 18.3 MATE. Tune In plugin is successfully working on a standard vlc version, but I can't find the specific location to copy plugin for flatpak version.

Answer (score 0):

By referring to [flatpak's wiki page](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Filesystem), you can learn the flatpak's underlying structure. However, in order to access the path of installed apps on your machine, please visit `/var/lib/flatpak/app/` or `$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/`; be aware the possibility of the first path is high. Also, `$HOME` refers to `/home/user-name/`.